# AngularJS и cURL

Tags: php, angularjs, curl

Подскажите, можно с помощью AngularJS на сайте создать демо функцию, чтобы посетитель ввел url нажал на кнопку отправить и в блоке ниже получил результат от выполнения cURL (т.е. увидел сайт url которого ввел ранее **без перезагрузки**)?

Может это можно как-то проще сделать?

Спасибо!

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js">    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Сайт:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Введите свое имя">
      <hr>
      <h1>Привет {{yourName}}!</h1>


<?php

    // URL сайта
    $url = '{{yourName}}';

    // создание объекта curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    // используем User Agent браузера
    $user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);

    // задаем URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    // указываем что это POST запрос
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

    // задаем параметры запроса
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    // указываем, чтобы нам вернулось содержимое после запроса
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    /*
        Задаем параметры сохранени¤ cookie
        как правило Cookie необходимы для дальнейшей работы с авторизацией
    */

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');


    // выполняем запрос для авторизации
    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $postResult;
?>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос, как изменить код, чтобы он отображал сайт по нажатию на кнопку, к примеру, "Получить сайт"? Можно ли вообще это осуществить? Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону iframe